# How to get_results from the database and display sorted in a table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting, html-table

I am trying to display information from a table I created in my Wordpress plugin (code below) and I can display in the table without any issues but I am having trouble figuring out how to display in some sort of sorted order, I.E. sorted by row ID.

```
<?php

    echo "<table class='widefat'>"; // start a table in HTML
    echo "<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Serial Number</th>
                <th>UserID</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>AreaCode</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Serial Number</th>
                <th>UserID</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Area Code</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>";


    $result = $wpdb ->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_new_table ");
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr><td><input name='ID_selected' type='radio' value='" . $row->id. "' /></td><td>" . $row->id. "</td><td>" . $row->sn. "</td><td>" . $row->userid. " </td><td>" . get_user_display_name($row->userid) ."</td><td>"  . $row->name. "</td><td>" . $row->areacode. "</td><td>" . $row->phone. "</td><td>

        <a href='" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "&dbviewedit=" . $row->id . "'>View/Edit</a></td></tr>";


    }

    echo "</tbody></table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I figured it out :-)
$result = $wpdb ->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_new_table ");
becomes
$result = $wpdb ->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_new_table ORDER BY id DESC ");
Then I just spotted John Smiths answer! thanks mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to adjust the SQL request, since the result is already **not ordered**

```
SELECT columnname FROM tablename ORDER BY columnname ASC|DESC
```

I hope this is what you're looking for